# use boto3 to upload file to s3 boto3.exceptions.S3UploadFailedError: An error occurred (QuotaExceeded) when calling the PutObject operation: Unknown

Tags: python, boto3

```
params = dict(service_name="s3", endpoint_url="****",
              aws_access_key_id="****",
              aws_secret_access_key="****")
s3 = boto3.client(**params)
response = s3.upload_file(localfile, bucket, key=key)
```

boto3.exceptions.S3UploadFailedError: An error occurred (QuotaExceeded) when calling the PutObject operation: Unknown

Comment: I see you are sepcifying endpoint_url. Are you connecting to AWS s3 or some compatible services like localstack?

Answer (score 0):

There is a limit on quotas that you can operate when using Boto3 for AWS. Some are adjustable, some are not. From your code, we don't see the file size, so this might be it as well. Here is the page for S3 and its quotas limit [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/s3.html)

Comment: I try a little size file also throws this exception ,I don't know what is the reason,zhe boto3 version :1.24.66